# In *ngIf directive: how to store returned value from a function in a variable and use it in the very same *ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-template

My use case is following:

1. I have a function that returns an array
2. I want to render a component conditionally - if an array exists and its length is greater than zero.
3. I want to pass this returned array as an `@Input()` to this component.

Because content of the array is computed I don't want to call this function twice and using getter would also be not helpful for that reason.

I have tried many different ways, just to list few:

```
<order-list *ngIf="customer.getOrders() as orders && orders.length > 0" [orders]="orders" ></order-list>
<order-list *ngIf="(customer.getOrders() as orders) && orders.length > 0" [orders]="orders" ></order-list>
<order-list *ngIf="(customer.getOrders()) as orders && (orders.length > 0)" [orders]="orders" ></order-list>
```

Unfortunately I keep getting bunch of errors:

> Template parse errors: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase'
> of undefined ("<div> 
>  Parser Error: Unexpected token &&, expected
> identifier, keyword, or string at column
>
> Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 23
>
> [ERROR ->]*ngIf="(customer.getOrders() as orders) && orders.length >
> 0"

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vtz1zm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html) with above issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up with a solution.

Instead of using *logical conjunction* in one `*ngIf` directive **I have wrapped my component with `<ng-container>`** and put my first condition in its `*ngIf` and then another `*ngIf` direct in component itself, so it is still AND of both conditions and it works like a charm since according to documentation:

> The Angular <ng-container> is a grouping element that doesn't
> interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the
> DOM.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="customer.getOrders() as orders">
    <order-list *ngIf="orders.length > 0" [orders]="orders" ></order-list>
</ng-container>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhr6kc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html) with the solution.